# datepicker and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

I have a problem with the use of the datepicker in Internet explorer. In all other browsers there isn't a problem, just with IE.

the code I use is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() { 
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true, 
                continuous: true
            });

            $( ".tcal" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "both",
                minDate: '-122Y',
                maxDate:'0',
                 yearRange: "-122",
                buttonImage: "/images/kalender3.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
              $( ".tver" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showOn: "both",
                    buttonImage: "/images/kalender3.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    minDate: '0',
                     maxDate: '+1Y',
                });
             $('.tcal,.tver').datepicker('option', $.extend({showMonthAfterYear: false},$.datepicker.regional['<?php print(($lng=='1')?'nl':'fr');?>']));
              $('.tcal,.tver').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
});


} ) ( jQuery );

</script>
```

But this won't work in Internet Explorer. On my home page I have the slider, and it also won't work anymore. But it will work when I place those parts in comment:

```
$( ".tcal" ).datepicker({
            /*  changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "both",
                minDate: '-122Y',
                maxDate:'0',
                 yearRange: "-122",
                buttonImage: "/images/kalender3.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true*/
            });
              $( ".tver" ).datepicker({
                    /*changeMonth: true,
                    showOn: "both",
                    buttonImage: "/images/kalender3.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    minDate: '0',
                     maxDate: '+1Y',*/
                });
```

Does someone knows where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of IE don't allow trailing commas. If you remove the comma after

```
maxDate: '+1Y'
```

does it work?

Comment: Yes thank you, I thought it would be something like that, but for a reason, every time I looked over that last comma. thanks so much;